# Number Sign in Instructions (Motorolla 68k)

Tags: assembly

Is the number sign actually needed when performing Instructions on the Motorolla 68k? For instance, If I have the two move instructions:

```
MOVE #5678,D2
```

and the other:

```
MOVE 5678,D2
```

I'm trying to use the 68k simulator, but for some reason mine isn't displaying the new value in each data register. So I'm not exactly sure if the number sign does matter. My Textbook for reference, fails to mention this anywhere. Does it make a difference at all?

Comment: Yes. The first instruction loads the constant 5678 into register D2 while the second loads the value at 5678 into D2 (though your assembler may choke unless you specify a size).

Comment: So they do produce a different result? Both on an emulator and on the actual microprocessor.

Comment: Indeed. Unless the value 5678 happens to be stored at address 5678 of memory. In any event I would suggest that you look into why your simulator is acting up, or alternatively find yourself a different one.

Comment: Which simulator, which emulator, which text book? The more details you give the easier it is to answer. However it looks like @doynax has already given you the correct answer. Shame it is in the comments and not the answers...